# Who passed the "args" to the main method?

Tags: c#, java

I tried to run a small c# and java program (using VS and NetBeans not from the command line) and print the value of the args[0] but I got an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.
I know that the `args` is for passing in command line parameters but it is **still** in the main method any way, So how the program will run if there is no `args` parameter passed to it ?

Comment: It checks first the length of the array args ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *So how the program will run if there is no args  parameter passed to it ?*
>   When the program is created a new array is allocated and filled with the values from the command line.

If there are none ( because you didn't specify them in your IDE )  the array will be empty ( not null, at least not in Java )

Yo avoid having your `IndexOutOfRangeException` you'll have to either don't use the argument, or assign a default value and validate the args array length.

For instance ( in Java )

```
public class YourClass {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {  
          String param = "someDefault";
          // validate args.length 
          if( args.length > 0 ) { // if there is a parameter
              param = args[0]; // use it 
          }
          // continue with "param" already defined.

    }
 }
```

Comment: so it will be empty and not null , so the program will run fine...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Java allows for empty arrays; i.e.

```
String[] args = new String[0];
```

Since `index >= args.length`, the exception is consistent.

On this particular topic, one additional note: unlike C programs etc, arg 0 is not the program itself. So it is quite common to have `main(String[])` getting called with an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no arguments, the array will be empty - if no array were passed you would have had an `NullReferenceException` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are only elements in the args[] array if you pass them on the command line.

```
java my.test.MyTest arg1 arg2
```

This will result in the arguments arg1 and arg2 being passed in the arg[] array.  If you passed no arguments, then the arg[] array is length 0, thus accessing any index will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly reasonable in some cases to not include any args when you invoke a command line exe.  The `args` parameter is there in order for you to tell whether or not args were passed, and if so what they were.